# Error in configuring multiple networks using weave network driver plugin for docker

Tags: networking, docker, weave

I am going through an article [weave net driver](http://docs.weave.works/weave/latest_release/plugin.html) and was trying my hands on it. I was able to use the default `weavemesh` driver for container-to-container communication on single host. The issue comes when i try to create multiple networks using `weave` network driver plugin. I get the following error.

```
[ankit@local-machine]$ docker network create -d weave netA
Error response from daemon: failed to parse pool request for address space "GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": cannot find address space GlobalDefault (most likely the backing datastore is not configured)
```

Now, as i understand from docker documentation at [Getting Started with Docker Multi-host Networking](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay.md) , It needs a key value store to be configured. I was wondering if my understanding is correct? Is there any way to create multiple networks over `weave` network to achieve network isolation. I want to be able to segregate network traffic for one container from another container running on the same box.

There is a new `weave 1.4 plugin` [docker networking without cluster store plugin](http://www.weave.works/docker-networking-without-cluster-store-plugin/) announcement recently which says it supports docker networking without external cluster store. how does it exactly work. its not very clear if it could be used to create multiple networks over `weave`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/1688) asked:

> Did you start the docker daemon with --cluster-store?
>
> You need to pass peers ips to weave launch-router `$peers` when starting docker with `--cluster-store` and `--cluster-advertise`.

The doc mentions:

> The Weave plugin actually provides two network drivers to Docker
>
> - one named `weavemesh` that can operate without a cluster store and
> - one named `weave` that can only work with one (like Docker’s overlay driver).

Hence the need to [Set up a key-value store](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay.md#step-1-set-up-a-key-value-store) first.

If you are using the `weave` plugin, your understanding is correct.

[PR 1738](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/pull/1738) has more on the new weave 1.4+ ability to operate *without* a keystore with the `weavemesh` driver. [Its doc does mention](http://docs.weave.works/weave/latest_release/plugin.html):

> If you do create additional networks using the `weavemesh` driver, containers attached to them will be able to communicate with containers attached to weave; there is no isolation between those networks.

But [PR 1742](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/1742) is still open "Allow user to specify a subnet range for each docker host".

Comment: I have added some more information to the question about `weave 1.4 plugin` . can it be used to achieve multiple network creation over `weave` without cluster store?

Comment: @AnkitKumar without cluster store means weavemesh, not weave

Comment: yes, got it..just read the release notes for `weave 1.4.0 plugin`

Comment: @AnkitKumar were you using the weave 1.4+ or a weave 1.3 or before?

Comment: I am using weave 1.4+